# How should I use all combinations in applicative

Tags: haskell

I encountered with a haskell problem.
Here is the question.

```hs
toList $ fromList [(+),(*)] <*> fromList [1..3] <*> fromList [10,100,1000] =
    [11,101,1001,12,102,1002,13,103,1003,10,100,1000,20,200,2000,30,300,3000]
```

`toList` is a function that convert the `Tree` type into `list` and `fromList` is to convert a `list` to `Tree` Type.

And my job is to implement the `pure` and the `<*>` operator of Applicative Class.
Here is my implement.

```hs
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Applicative Tree where
  pure = Leaf
  Leaf f       <*> t            = f <$> t
  Branch t1 t2 <*> Leaf a       = t1 <*> Leaf a
  Branch t1 t2 <*> Branch t3 t4 = Branch (t1 <*> t3) (t2 <*> t4)
```

But I do not know how to firgue out the "all combinations". Please help me.

Comment: The `Branch t1 t2 <*> Leaf a` looks odd. Why work only with the left subtree?

Comment: I don't know. I am confusing about haskell programming. I just learned it. I feel like the leaf should only contact with the left subtree? I don't know

Comment: As a hint: I think you should only need two patterns for your `(<*>)` implementation, namely, `Leaf f <*> t` and `Branch fs fs' <*> t`. The second argument, `t` in both cases, should be treated completely uniformly. Sometimes adding constraints makes a problem easier (because there are fewer candidate solutions to think about)!

Comment: Thanks for your hint! But I still do not know how to make "all combinations" in the applicative. Could you please tell me something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct with the `pure`.

As to the `<*>`, you've also started right with the `Leaf f <*> t` clause. Just go with it, by small steps. For example:

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Leaf a)     =  Leaf (f a)
  fmap f (Branch l r) =  Branch (fmap f l) (fmap f r)

instance Applicative Tree where
  pure x  =  Leaf x
  --
  Leaf f     <*> t       =  f     <$> t
  t          <*> Leaf a  =  ($ a) <$> …
  Branch l r <*> t       =  Branch (… <*> t) (r <*> …)
```

You don't have to have a complete solution in your head before you write the code. Just start writing it, clause by clause, enumerating all the possibilities you could think of (meaning, *structural* possibilities for each of the arguments -- in this case, whether it's a leaf or a branch).  You can always remove a redundant clause later.

---

The above definition of `<*>` works by *recursion*. And recursion works by *assuming* that we *already have* our definition for the the simpler cases, so we can build the result for a more complex case from solutions for its simpler sub-parts. Making sure that if the solutions for the sub-problems are correct -- and they are, by the assumption -- we combine those partial solutions properly so that the combined solution is correct for the whole problem:

```
recursion (problem) = solution where
  problem has part1, part2, ...
  sol1 = recursion(part1)
  sol2 = recursion(part2)
  ....
  solution is sol1, sol2, ..., combined properly together
```

And so in our case, when `tree1` is `Branch l r`,

```
tree1 <*> tree2 = 
  case tree1 of Branch l r -> 
    let sol1 = l <*> tree2
        sol2 = .....
    in
       combineTogether sol1 sol2
   where
     combineTogether subtree1 subtree2 = .....
```

Just finish it up and try it at the REPL. See that it works all by itself, through the magic of recursion, since we've also defined how to handle the simplest cases directly:

```
  ....
  case tree1 of Leaf f -> 
  ....
```

(treat the above as bits of pseudo-syntax).

---

Thus the last line of our proposed definition,

```
  Branch l r <*> t       =  Branch (… <*> t) (r <*> …)
```

reads: all combinations of a tree which is `Branch l r`, with another tree `t`, is *a new tree*, which is `Branch new_l new_r`, where *`new_l`* holds all combinations of the .... with `t`, and the other one, *`new_r`*, holds the other combinations (just go ahead and make the most obvious substitutions for the dots there).

Just like with lists, where all combinations of `[(1+),(2+)]` with `[30,40]` is the list which combines all combinations of `[(1+)]` with `[30,40]`, and all the combinations of `[(2+)]` with `[30,40]`:

```
      [(1+),(2+)] <*> [30,40]
=
   ([(1+)] ++ [(2+)]) <*> [30,40]
=
([(1+)] <*> [30,40]) ++ ([(2+)] <*> [30,40])
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am still confused about making "all combinations" in applicative. So, do you mean I can just use `Branch l r <*> t       =  Branch (… <*> t) (r <*> …)` to make "all combinations"?

Comment: Yes, you need to finish the code by replacing the dots with something that makes sense. If a tree is a branch with two subtrees, and we combine it with another tree, then the result is the branch with two subtrees where each is the result of combining each of the .... with the .... . (it's easier in code than in words, heh).

Comment: @Vic I've edited with another clarification. for the "possibilities" the intention is, _structural_ possibilities for each of the arguments -- in this case, whether it's a leaf or a branch.

Comment: you're welcome. :) you can accept one of the answers, the one that you feel was the most helpful, if any; to signal that the issue is resolved. (accept == click on the big empty check-mark near the answer to make it green) I hope it is indeed resolved, yes? @Vic

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to notice that leaf trees are monads.

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Control.Applicative (Applicative (..))

instance Monad Tree where
  Leaf a >>= f = f a
  Branch l r >>= f = Branch (l >>= f) (r >>= f)

instance Applicative Tree where
  pure = Leaf
  liftA2 = liftM2
```

Identity laws (`pure a >>= f = f a`, `m >>= pure = m`):

```
pure a >>= f = Leaf a >>= f = f a

m >>= pure
-- Leaf case
Leaf a >>= pure
= -- def of >>=
pure a
= -- def of pure
Leaf a

-- Branch case
Branch l r >>= pure
= -- def of >>=
Branch (l >>= pure) (r >>= pure)
= -- structural induction
Branch l r
```

Associative law (`((m >>= f) >>= g) = (m >>= (f >=> g))`) :

```
(m >>= f) >>= g
-- when m = Leaf a
(Leaf a >>= f) >>= g
= --def of >>=
f a >>= g
= -- beta abstraction
(\q -> f q >>= g) a
= -- def of >>=
Leaf a >>= (\q -> f q >>= g)
= -- assumption
m >>= (\q -> f q >>= g)

-- when m = Branch l r
(Branch l r >>= f) >>= g
= -- def of >>=
Branch (l >>= f) (r >>= f) >>= g
= -- def of >>=
Branch ((l >>= f) >>= g) ((r >>= f) >>= g)
= -- Structural induction
Branch (l >>= (\q -> f q >>= g)) (r >>= (\q -> f q >>= g))
= -- def of >>=
Branch l r >>= (\q -> f q >>= g)
= -- assumption
m >>= (\q -> f q >>= g)
```

---

To avoid certain (usually tiny) space leaks, you can change the definition of `>>=` a bit so it can inline:

```
instance Monad Tree where
  m >>= f = go m
    where
       go (Leaf a) = f a
       go (Branch l r) = Branch (go l) (go r)
```

---

Thus the applicative combination is

```
fs <*> xs 
= -- (<*>) = ap and the def of ap
do { f <- fs
   ; x <- xs
   ; return (f x)
   }
= -- do notation rewrite
fs >>= (\ f -> xs >>= (\ x -> pure (f x)))
= -- re-write in terms of Leaf and Branch
  -- with explicit case clauses
case fs of 
 Leaf f -> ...
 Branch fl fr -> ...
```

thus deriving the definition.

Comment: @WillNess, I wasn't familiar with the term "beta abstraction", so I just used "beta reduction" in the other direction. That's also how I actually constructed it: started at both ends and met in the middle.

Comment: that's what google [taught me](http://foldoc.org/beta+abstraction).  I just guessed. :)